# How to get children objects from parent name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am using this piece of code to see if the user is hovering over the object by the name of "townhall" `hit.collider.gameObject.name == "townhall"`

But, what I want is to see if the user is hovering over the children of the object by the name of "townhall"

Comment: If townhall is an empty gameObject with no collider, then it should work, if it doesn’t, then make sure that the colliders on the child objects are there.

Comment: @ken no it won't .. if it was an empty object there would be no collision in the first place ;)

Comment: Have you tried going through the [`parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) or put a specific component on the parent object so you can simply search for it via [`GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html) ?

Comment: @derHugo I was talking about having an empty game object as a parent and then objects with colliders would be the children.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent object "townhall" has a specific script on it (ie. TownHall.cs), what you can do is check if a parent of the object in question (hit.collider) has that script. Something like this.

```
var townHall = hit.collider.GetComponentInParent<TownHall>();
if (townHall != null)
{
    // The hit object or one of its parents has the townhall script
    //
}
```

Be aware that the hit object itself can return the specific script when using GetComponentInParent.  Just check if it is the townhall object, either by name or some other determining factor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one might be helpfull,
hit.collider.transform.parent.gameObject.name == "townhall"

Comment: You can skip the `.collider` and `.gameObject` and directly access `hit.transform.parent.name` ;)